# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to display the "Hello World" into the browser by using react

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const myelement = <h1>Hello World</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(myelement, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="react"></div>

        <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However I keep getting the error as said in the headline of the post. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: quote marks around the content: const myelement = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";

Comment: are you using babel? See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx) or [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project)

Comment: I've quoted the sintax, however a new error arrived being: Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “react”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.  Is there a way to solve this thanks

Comment: Im not using babel

Comment: Make your life easier and use something like `create-react-app` to get started with react faster

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `babel` to use `JSX`. And the `id` of the root element should match the `id` in the `ReactDOM.render` function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      const myelement = <h1>Hello World</h1>;

      ReactDOM.render(myelement, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```